# Two class interaction

Tags: c#, oop

```
class Game
{
    byte[,] map = new byte[5, 5];
    Player p;

    public Game()
    {
        p = new Player();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        p.Update();
    }
}

class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        //init...
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //this code needs map
    }
}
```

How can I reach `Game`'s `map` in `Player.Update()`? Most obivous solution is adding a `map` parameter to `Player.Update()` of course. But this way just seems wrong to me. I recently read C++ book and know about pointers. I was thinking of adding pointer to `map` in `Player` class and use it in `Player.Update()`. I know C# has pointers too but never used them. Is it good thing to use them in this situation? Or perhaps there is better solution to this situation not involving pointers? I know I'm very bad at OOP.

Comment: Pointers? No. It's C#, not C++. That's not a proper case for pointers in C#.

Comment: you should return something instead. cycles can cause problems later in design.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the value of `map` from `Game.Update()` to `Player.Update()`? Alternatively, if you want to protect the `map` instance, then you can pass the `Game` reference to `Player.Update()` and then provide methods or properties in `Game` to access the information in `map` without exposing the `map` object itself. Note that a C# reference type value (i.e. a "reference") is roughly equivalent to a C++ pointer. You don't need to use actual C# pointers to accomplish the same result.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have bad habit: I always try to optimize things before I even write the code. In this case I thought that passing `map` to `Player.Update(byte[,] asd)` would be inefficient because it copies array by value and `Update` is called often.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek what's the proper case for pointers in C#?

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean? return what? how can cycles can cause problems?

Comment: @foxneSs You can read more about pointer types on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you need to find out what a reference type is and what an object reference is. This is essential to working with C#. Since both of your classes are reference types all variables you declare with that type are references to objects.

You can simply pass a `Game` to `Player.Update` to pass a reference to the existing game.

Comment: Do you mean it should be like `Player.Update(Game a)`?

Comment: Pretty much. You can pass a reference to your Game any way you like.